# connect with curl script output "* Empty reply from server", but Fiddler to get data is ok

Tags: curl, fiddler

when I using fiddler 4 can capture the following link:

```
URL
```

with following **RAW** header :

```
GET http://'URL' HTTP/1.1
Host: 'URL'
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: 'URL'
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: win007BfCookie=null; bfWin007FirstMatchTime=2019,7,13,08,00,00; UM_distinctid=16c8b3edbf14fc-062d46919e565-14367b40-190140-16c8b3edbf22e7; win0168BfFavoriteCookie=1
```

output from fiddler 4

```
sData[1743630]=[[0.98,0,0.86,0.82,0.25,1.04,,,],[2.55,3.20,2.40,2.07,3.35,3.15,,,],[0.88,2.25,0.94,1.03,2.5,0.81,,,],[0.90,0,0.94,1.23,0.25,0.67,,,],[1.06,1.00,0.76,1.04,1,0.80,,,],[3.15,2.03,3.20,2.69,2.08,3.70,,,]];
```

but when i execute the following script with curl :

```
curl -vvv 'URL' -H 'Referer: 'URL'
```

output from curl (windows cmd shell):

```
curl -vvv 'URL' -H 'Referer: 'URL'
* Could not resolve host: 'http
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'http
*   Trying 47.75.149.10:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 'URL' (47.75.149.10) port 80 (#1)
> GET /' HTTP/1.1
> Host: 'URL'
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */* 
>
* Recv failure: Connection was reset
* Closing connection 1
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

output from curl (linux shell):

```
root@xxxxx:~# curl -vvv 'URL' -H 'Referer: 'URL'
*   Trying 47.52.91.249...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.win0168.com (47.52.91.249) port 80 (#0)
> GET 'URL' HTTP/1.1
> Host: 'URL'
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Referer: 'URL'
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: your error makes no sense, most likely you have some invisible/un-printable characters in the url when executing the command. save the command to a text file and open the text file in a hex editor (for example [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) if you're on windows, or [Bless](https://github.com/bwrsandman/Bless) if you're on Linux), any bytes in the http:// part that doesn't belong there?

Comment: dear, i executing the command in the windows cmd shell, thanks !

Comment: oh, windows's cmd shell does not use single quotes `'` to quote arguments, i think they use a combination of double quotes and percentage signs. if you want a terminal with linux-style shell arguments in Windows, then install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: Dear, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

win0168.com blocks curl. the block is implemented via User-Agent header detection. either use wget, or set a fake useragent that does not include the phrase "curl". for the record, your curl's User-Agent is

```
User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
```

but if you the curl name in reverse for the UA, you will get the response,

```
curl -A 'lruc' -H 'Referer: http://www.win0168.com/' 'http://www.win0168.com/vbsxml/goalBf3.xml?r=0071565705912000'
```

(`lruc` is `curl` written backwards.)